# Is it possible to use EL inside <p:dialog> header?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to use EL inside header of a PrimeFaces 3.5 dialog?

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="personneDialog" id="personDlg" hideEffect="explode">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Details of: #{personneMB.selectedPerson.name}"
    </f:facet>
```

This prints only an empty string:

[image]

Comment: Why should not be possible? Have you tried ?

Comment: What is real problem here. Do you have exceptions, or nothing is displayed or ... Please post real problem. Result of EL is written to page during rendering. What are you expecting?

Comment: @partlov there is no error/exception throwed! I added a picture, I expect to have the name of the person show up in the header

Comment: @SupHu so `personneMB.selectedPerson.name` was null during page rendering. This is really not enough information to tell more. Debug and see value of `name` property.

Comment: @partlov do I need to add a breakpoint next to this line of code inside my anaged bean private Personne selectedPersonne; ?

Comment: @partlov or do I need to set a watchpoint next to the name property of my POJO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem by updating the dialog not just the panelGrid inside

the facet header belong to dialog that's why it didn't get updated in the first place.